# How to whitelist a class?

Tags: android, proguard, whitelist

How do i white list an android activity having java class name as Abc.java and xml as activity_abc.xml

I've used Proguard and i want to keep/whitelist that class in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep class like this:

```
-keep class com.yourproject.YourClass**
```

To keep all package:

```
-keep class com.yourproject.model.** { *; }
```

Comment: Thanks, I also wanted to know how do i keep the whole package?

Comment: are those * necessary? Consider my package name as com.abc.model

Comment: Yeah, I guess so.